# How to know the connected Hive Server in java

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to know which Hive Server is connected currently through Zookeeper. I wanted to automate my testing and wanted to know which hive server is connected through zookeeper.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Wild guess: does `connection.getMetaData().getURL()` return the original URL, referencing the ZK ensemble, or the actual URL retrieved from ZK?

Comment: Also, try to run statement `set env:HOSTNAME` just in case that environment variable was set for the HiveServer2 process. But that's not likely for a Linux service.

Answer (score 0):

Run statement `set hive.server2.thrift.bind.host`

`set` is not a standard SQL command, but in Hive HQL dialect, it enables you to read/write Hive properties (also Java properties, even environment variables).

In case you have multiple HS2 instances on the same host, retrieve the port also.
=> depending on `hive.server2.transport.mode`, check `hive.server2.thrift.port` or `hive.server2.thrift.http.port`

---

In case you run a Cloudera distro, you may also run `set env:HIVE_LOGFILE` since log file names include the hostname *(makes log collection easier for Cloudera Manager, I guess)*